# NextJS react-query map over data issues

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS (13.4.12), and i wanted to try react-query for data fetching. Prior the react-query i used a custom useFetch hook, and everything worked normally.

I've setup react query as recommended by making a client component provider.tsx:

```
function Providers({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient())

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default Providers;
```

I have a api service class where I have this method to fetch my data:

```
  async GetAlphabet() {
    try {
      const alphabet = await fetch('/api/character');
      return alphabet;
    }
    catch (error) {
      return new Response("Failed to retrieve the alphabet characters", { status: 500 });
    }
  }
```

And this is my page.tsx where I want to fetch my data and display a list of alphabet characters:

```
"use client"

import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import ApiService from "../../../services/api";

interface Alphabet {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  typeId: number;
  languageId: number;
  language: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
  type: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
}

export default function Page() {

  const { isLoading, isSuccess, data, error } = useQuery({ queryKey: ['alphabet'], queryFn: () => ApiService.GetAlphabet() })

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Korean alphabet</h1>
      <ul className="flex gap-1 text-4xl">
        {
          data?.map((item: Alphabet) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </>
  )

}
```

On this line "data?.map((item: Alphabet) => (" i get this error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Response'.

How do i resolve that?
I tryed checking if data is a array, then my component rendered without a error, but my list was not displayed. I checked and the request was successful in the chrome network tab - the fetched data was a json with data according to the Alphabet interface.

I also tryed adding a check for isSuccess, but same result. Hope anyone can pinpoint what I am doing wrong. If more information is needed, I would be happy to provide.

Comment: the `fetch` response must be parsed from json by `await response.json()`, you can then use the returned value. and I am not sure if returning `Response` instance as an error is a good decision or not. (the documentation uses `throw new Error(...)` to throw error) https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-functions

Comment: PS. In the App router, a better solution to fetch data is to fetch data in a server component and pass the result as props to children where they need it. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns

Comment: Yeah i forgot the .json(), i know i could pass it as props, but its just a hobbie project to try and play with react-query. You want to write the solution so i can mark it?

Comment: sure :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to parse the response data using `.json()` method. additionally, as per [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/query-functions#handling-and-throwing-errors), to determine a query has errored, the query function must throw. moreover, the fetch function does not throw errors by default, so we have to check if the `ok` property is false and then throw ([read from documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/query-functions#usage-with-fetch-and-other-clients-that-do-not-throw-by-default)).

```js
async GetAlphabet() {
    const resp = await fetch('/api/character');
    
    if (!resp.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to retrieve the alphabet characters')
    }

    return resp.json();
}
```

PS. If you are using the app router in NextJS, the recommended solution is to fetch data in server components and pass the results as props to children. you can read more at [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns).